# Using GCD and Core Data causes crash

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, magicalrecord

I retrieve data back from our server and I need to process it.

For each key, I create a `NSManagedObject`.  Each object is created in the same context. I am using Magical Record.

```
-(id)init {
    if (self = [super init]){
        self.context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Threading:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0);
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

for (id key in boundariesDictionary) {
    dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
        DLog(@"nsthread: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);

        NSString *boundaryIDString;

        if ([key isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
            boundaryIDString = key;
        }
        else if ([key isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
            boundaryIDString = [key stringValue];
        }

        if (boundaryIDString) {
            DLog(@"boundaryIDString: %@", boundaryIDString)

            NSDictionary *boundaryDictionary = [boundariesDictionary objectForKey:key];

            Boundary *boundary = [Boundary MR_findFirstWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"boundaryID == %@ AND api == %@", [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[boundaryIDString integerValue]], self.serverCall.API] inContext:self.context];

            if ([boundaryDictionary objectForKey:AVI_NAME]) {
                if (boundary == nil) {
                    DLog(@"creating boundary %@", boundaryIDString);

                    boundary = [Boundary MR_createInContext:self.context];
                    boundary.boundaryID = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[boundaryIDString integerValue]];
                }
            }

            boundary = [self processBoundary:boundary fromBoundaryDictionary:boundaryDictionary];
         }
    }
}
```

[self processBoundary] just takes the dictionary and sets it to the managed object's attributes.

```
if ([boundaryDictionary objectForKey:@"name"]) {
    boundary.name = [boundaryDictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
}

//more data processing
```

This is causing an error though:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSCFSet: 0x1776f7f0> was mutated while being enumerated.'
```

It runs fine if I don't use the same context for each thread.

I don't understand what set other then the `NSDictionary` boundariesDictionary that i'm enumerating through. I am not mutating boundariesDictionary at all, only copying the data into core data.

When I PO the object (0x1776f7f0 in this case), I get a list of `Boundary` objects in a set. Those `Boundary` objects would only exist in the `NSManagedObjectContext` "set", I don't add them to an `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, or `NSSet`. But I don't believe I enumerate over that set. I do mutate it by creating new boundary objects to it.

I think there is something going on that I don't understand or quite grasp yet.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

```
    for (id key in boundariesDictionary) {
        NSString *boundaryIDString;

        if ([key isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
            boundaryIDString = key;
        }
        else if ([key isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
            boundaryIDString = [key stringValue];
        }

        if (boundaryIDString) {
            [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
                DLog(@"saveWithBlock thread: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);

                NSDictionary *boundaryDictionary = [boundariesDictionary objectForKey:key];

                Boundary *boundary = [Boundary MR_findFirstWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"boundaryID == %@ AND api == %@", [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[boundaryIDString integerValue]], self.serverCall.API] inContext:localContext];

                if ([boundaryDictionary objectForKey:AVI_NAME]) {
                    if (boundary == nil) {
                        boundary = [Boundary MR_createInContext:localContext];
                        boundary.boundaryID = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[boundaryIDString integerValue]];
                    }

                    boundary = [self processBoundary:boundary fromBoundaryDictionary:boundaryDictionary];

                    if (boundary == nil) {
                        //Prompt Error
                    }
                    else {
                        for (NSNumber *groupID in groupIDs) {
                            if ([groupID isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
                                Group *group = [Group MR_findFirstWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"groupID == %@ OR groupID == 0 AND api == %@", groupID, self.serverCall.API]];

                                if (group != nil) {
                                    group.lastUpdated = [NSDate date];

                                    [group addBoundariesObject:boundary];
                                }
                                else {
                                    DLog(@"group %@ DNE", groupID);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                DLog(@"saveWithBlock completion Block | time: %f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startTime]);
            }];
        }
    }
```

So for my `Group` 29 should see all the boundaries I'm creating, but its not.  Its inconsistent. Sometimes sees all, sometimes some, and sometimes none.

Also, I often see

```
NO CHANGES IN ** BACKGROUND SAVING (ROOT) ** CONTEXT - NOT SAVING
```

in the log. Its also inconsistent on how many of these messages I see, while the context that do save will insert more then 1 object.

Not sure if that is how it should be behaving, seems like it should be a 1-to-1 ratio if each block has its own context and each block only creates 1 object.

I log each thread ID, and it is creating a new thread for each block. No thread ID is being logged twice, so the threads shouldn't be being reused.

Answer (score 0):

Managed object contexts are not thread safe, you must not use them or any managed objects/sets/data structures/whatever they might return from different queues or threads.

I don't know if magical record supports it, but you should definitely be using queue containment for your contexts, and then you have to do everything within the context of the MOC's private queue.

If you use thread containment, you must guarantee that the context and any managed objects created by the context are always serially accessed, which you're absolutely not doing in the code above.

Comment: Magical record helps reduce boilerplate coding and helps with threading. It lets you create contexts and to save back to a main context that all new context spawn from.  It helps to make core data easier to be thread safe. At this point, I am not saving it yet. Just trying to create them all in the same context.

Comment: @Log139 I know what Magical Record is and it's not doing anything helpful for you threading-wise with the code above. The code it's using is not thread safe. You can't legally do what you're trying to do above with CoreData. CoreData requires you to access the context serially.

Comment: No, core data can certainly be used with threads and queues if you follow the simple rule that your managed object and contexts should never cross thread boundaries. The problem here is that gcd queues are not threads. They reuse threads, so you're likely violating that simple rule by tying your context to the thread and reusing it.

Comment: @casademora That is what I said, and it's not really about thread boundaries as much as it is serial access to the context and the managed objects. For example, you won't have a problem if you use thread containment and a serial queue, even if the work blocks end up executing on different threads. Here, he is accessing the same context and managed objects across multiple threads/queues simultaneously. That is totally illegal with CoreData.

Comment: Sure, a serial queue with a single confinement context may work now, but changing the queue type will eventually lead to crashes where code once worked. In general, the methods I've prescribed are good practices from hard learned lessons from many app crashes in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

You're issue is that gcd queues a threads are not a one to one mapping.  GCD reuses threads, and thus your are likely crossing thread boundaries unknowingly here. My suggestion is to simply create a new context and stop using contextForCurrentThread. I wrote more details about the issues [on my blog](http://saulmora.com/2013/09/15/why-contextforcurrentthread-doesn-t-work-in-magicalrecord/). ContextForCurrentThread will be deleted in an upcoming release.

Comment: If he were using serial queues he might also consider `dispatch_[set/get]_specific` to associate contexts (or other objects) directly with queues rather than threads. He's not though, so this is a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: That's totally wrong. He's accessing the context and managed objects simultaneously from multiple threads. Thread containment works because if all access to context/objects are on the same thread, it's guaranteed to be serial access. You can also use a serial queue with thread containment and get the same effect, as long as all access is always done from within a block executing on the serial queue. Here, he's using a global queue, so even creating a context won't help since it's still going to violate CoreData's multithreading policies.

Comment: @casademora I implemented the [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^{}]. It creates the new entities, but it is having a hard time saving relationships. Each Boundary needs to be set to a Group. The group.boundaries is inconsistent. Say I have 20 Boundary objects an all should have a relationship with a Group. Sometimes the group has 10 boundaries, sometimes 16, sometimes all or no relationships. I'll update my question to include how I set the relationships.

Comment: Updated the question with the results after changing to [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^{}].

Comment: Make sure you're also creating your Groups in the same context as your boundaries using the inContext: parameter. It looks like you aren't doing that.

Comment: I create the groups in a different context, but I save them via `MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait` and then refetch them in the block's local context. In my head, they get saved to the default context and then I refetch them. Is this a mistake?